# NDsolve set of pdes with minus power

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve set of pdes as below

```
p=0.01;B=10;n=100;S0=0.01;T0=0.01;
pdes = {D[S[t, z], z] == -2*Im[k]*S[t, z], 3/2*n*D[T[t, z], t] == 2*Im[k]*S[t, z]} /.k-> (1-n/(1-B+I*p*n*T[t,z]^(-3/2)))^(1/2);
bc = {S[t, 0] == S0};
ic = {T[0, z] == T0};
s = NDSolve[{pdes, ic, bc}, {S, T}, {t, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}]
ContourPlot[Evaluate[T[t, z] /.s], {t, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2},PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Then I get error message: *NDSolve`FEM`InitializePDECoefficients::femcnsd: The PDE coefficient -(((0. +0.795 I) S[t,z] (Im^[Prime])[Sqrt[1-100/(-9+(0. +0.0053 I) Power[<<2>>])]])/(Sqrt[1-100/(-9+(0. +0.0053 I)/T[<<2>>]^(3/2))] (-9+(0. +0.0053 I)/T[t,z]^(3/2))^2 T[t,z]^(5/2))) does not evaluate to a numeric scalar at the coordinate {0.05,0.05}; it evaluated to Indeterminate instead.*

If I use `T[t,z]^(3/2)` instead of `T[t,z]^(-3/2)`, it works.

Could any one help me to figure it out?

---

Strange, it is solved when I just multply fraction with `T[t,z]^{3/2}`,  it becomes

```
pdes = {D[S[t, z], z] == -2*Im[k]*S[t, z], 
3/2*n*D[T[t, z], t] == 2*Im[k]*S[t, z]} /.k ->(1-n*T[t, z]^(3/2)/(T[t, z]^(3/2) - B*T[t, z]^(3/2) + I*p*n))^(1/2);
```

I have to say that, although mma is very convinient to solve simple pde and ode, i have to give it up when encounting "complex" pdes. It waisted me too much time just to adjust the equations and find proper methods.

Comment: `NDSolve` is trying to calculate the derivative `Im'`.

Comment: What does it mean? Alex.

Comment: It uses a method for which it is necessary to calculate the derivative `Im'[]`. But this derivative is not defined therefore `it evaluated to Indeterminate instead`

Comment: Strange. It can be solved when I multiply T[t,z]^{3/2} in the fractions.

Comment: No, there is a message `NDSolve`FEM`DiscretizePDE::femdpop: The NDSolve`FEM`FEMStiffnessElements operator failed.`

Comment: I saw the message. But because the plot appears, I thought that it is still solved.  Do you think, it is not solved yet? MMA is too complicated, it seems to be better to write differential equation by myself.

Comment: By the way, does the message of "The FEMStiffnessElements operator failed" mean that the result is not trustable?

Comment: I would not trust. You solve a different equation there. Write the FDM code.